# Cassandra schema validation

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'm using Spring Data Cassandra to connect to my Cassandra DB. I've created the entity java objects (with the @Table annotation) to make some simple fetches from the DB.

I want to know how can I make a schema validation on startup like it's done in Hibernate for example.

Note that I read about query validation, but I'm interested in validating table name and column names.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such feature right now. Care to file an issue at https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATACASS/ and describe what you'd expect?